# Custom UIToolbar with UINavigationController for Pros

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

For weeks I've been scouring resources and searching for non-kiddo dev advice about making a custom-sized UIToolbar work in a UINavigationController-based app.  By "work" I mean a non-hackish approach that allows key things like graceful hide/show of the toolbar, swipe-to-hide, and other graceful animations.

Making a custom `UIToolbar` class instance that goes inside the `UINavigationController` instance that overrides `sizeThatFits:` changes the size as expected, but there's a couple unacceptable issues as a result.

So, here we have the common `sizeThatFits:` replacement offered by many:

```
    - (CGSize) sizeThatFits:(CGSize)inSize {
        CGSize sz = [super sizeThatFits:inSize];
        sz.height = SS_TOOLBAR_HEIGHT;
        return sz;
    }
```

Ok, great, the size is altered, but if you set breakpoints on that function, it's clear that something else is still banging away for that ol 44 pt height.  Try setting a breakpoint there and see how often it gets called -- seems fishy (this will come into play later).

Ok, fine, it changes the height as we like, so we move onto adding functionality so that the toolbar hides (w/ animation) on a touch or swipe.  Well, if we enable UINavigationController's `hidesBarsOnSwipe`, then there's two problems: the nav bar is tethered to the hiding (yuck), *and* the toolbar gets completely hidden so that brining it back is totally non-WYSIWYG.  Our design goal is to get the toolbar operating like a drawer that slides in/out on the appropriate swipe direction, independent of the nav bar.  Further rather than hiding the toolbar completely, we'd like to have a lil stub/tab thing maybe 10-20 pts tall that indicates the user can slide the toolbar back upward like a drawer back to its normal state.

So to do this, we alter `sizeThatFits:` in our UIToolbar derived class:

```
- (CGSize) sizeThatFits:(CGSize)inSize {
    CGSize sz = [super sizeThatFits:inSize];
    sz.height = _minimized ? SS_TOOLBAR_HEIGHT_MINIMIZED : SS_TOOLBAR_HEIGHT;
    return sz;
}
```

On a minimize state change we would naturally hide/show the appropriate subviews so it would appear normally or be, say, 15 pts high with a little grip-graphic ditty.  So the major issue with this approach is that now any attempts at toolbar animation to slide it in/out get totally b0rked thanks to `sizeThatFits:` getting called during animation and short-circuiting it.  Ok Apple, fine, let's try hacks like setting the destination size elsewhere with:

```
- (CGSize) sizeThatFits:(CGSize)inSize {
    CGSize sz = [super sizeThatFits:inSize];
    if ( _animationInProgress ) {
        sz.height = _minimized ? SS_TOOLBAR_HEIGHT_MINIMIZED : SS_TOOLBAR_HEIGHT;
    }
    return sz;
}
```

Well things just snowball at this point into insanity.  Calls to `sizeThatFits:` abound and attempts at drawer-like hide/show animation look even more broken as the 44 pt ghost size wins out, dorking everything up.

So, in short, I'm looking a pro dev to share info/suggestions on how to proceed with using a UINavigationController but having a toolbar with well-behaved animated drawer-like behavior.  I'll settle for almost anything at this point, just that the "minimized" state is WYSIWYG-friendly so the user can get the toolbar back.  Maybe one approach is to make a tiny floating UIView that sits at the bottom and is shown only when the toolbar is hidden (and when touched or swiped, the toolbar would be unhidden and animation would be fluid).  How and where would I persist such a "floating" view?

I guess what gets me about all this and why I feel like I'm posting for help in exasperation is that the needed toolbar functionality discussed here seems like functionality most iOS developers would absolutely welcome and would see as a major improvement to UINavigationController+UIToolbar's current limitations.

I have decent experience in iOS, but I'm a OS X and Win vet of maaaany moons, so help from other pro devs is HIGHLY appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding -intrinsicContentSize.

Comment: I don't think so.  That method isn't even called for a `UIToolbar` in a `UINavigationController`.  Derive a child class of UIToolbar, use it in a UINavigationController, set a breakpoint in its `intrinsicContentSize` implementation, and you'll wait as long as America has waiting for a pentagon and political structure that doesn't see everything either as a bombing target or natural resource possession.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1. Drag a new View Controller into the storyboard.
2. Drag a Toolbar onto that window.
3. Add constraints to the toolbar: Leading, Trailing, Bottom, Height.
4. Set the tag of the toolbar to 1.
5. Add a Container View to the view controller.
6. Add constraints:

   - Top Space to Top Layout Guide
   - Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide
   - Leading Space To Superview (**NOT MARGIN**)
   - Trailing Space to Superview
7. Delete the view controller that the container view links to.
8. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>-Drag from the container view to your navigation controller. Select “Embed.”
9. Move the Storyboard Entry Point (the arrow that fades in from the left) to the main view controller.
10. Subclass `UINavigationController`.
11. Override in your subclass:

    ```
    - (UIToolbar *)toolbar {
        UIToolbar *toolbar = (UIToolbar *)[self.parentViewController.view viewWithTag:1];
        if (!toolbar) {
            return super.toolbar; // prevent errors on app launch
        }
        return toolbar;
    }
    - (void)setToolbarHeight:(CGFloat)height {
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.toolbar.constraints) {
            if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
                constraint.constant = height;
            }
        }
        [self.parentViewController.view layoutSubviews];
        [self.toolbar layoutIfNeeded];
    }
    // if you need:
    - (CGFloat)toolbarHeight {
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.toolbar.constraints) {
            if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
                return constraint.constant;
                break;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    ```

**Note:** All views in the toolbar will stay stuck to the bottom of the toolbar.

**Note 2:** This works with animation, just set `self.toolbarHeight = ###` in an `-animateWithDuration:` method.

**Important:** If you are shrinking the toolbar’s height, make sure to set `toolbar.clipsToBounds` to `YES`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but can you elaborate?  It's not clear how this wouldn't have problems with the 44 invisible hand and the fact that `sizeThatFits` seems to interrupt or otherwise mess with animation.

Comment: @Drew This doesn’t require use of `-sizeThatFits:`.

Comment: I hear you, but I guess I'm saying the details seem fuzzy, and you didn't make it clear if this is a confirmed solution.  I'm "using" IB for this project, but literally just to instantiate the UINavigationController so you suggestion applies (everything else is created programmatically).  However, all the constraints in IB for the toolbar view are disabled (which makes me wonder if you have experience with this method).

Comment: I tried playing with this is different ways by adding constraints programmatically and the size/height of the toolbar never changed from 44.

Comment: So I tried to follow your steps but there's some discrepancies (have you even tried this approach!?).  Regardless, I see what the approach is about, but after trying it enough ways, I keep getting a fatal issue.   main() crashes on startup when `toolbar` is called because the UINavigationController's parentViewController is still nil. 

I sincerely appreciate your help JF, but if what you're suggesting is something that's not really tested then I'm not sure why you're suggesting someone else try it (not even mentioning that this is an experimental idea).

Comment: @Drew Sorry about that. I have improved  (and tested) the answer now. The only issue with this is that the gray hairline at the top of the toolbar is clipped when `clipsToBounds` is YES.